# Timer preventing program from exiting

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, minecraft

I'm writing a program which allows me to control a vanilla Minecraft server using python. The first thing I wanted to make is a auto-restart feature. Everything works fine except that I cannot do `sys.exit()` or similar things, I'm not sure but I think this is because of the `Timer`.

I tried `t.cancel()` but `t` is a local variable so it's complicated to play with it.

Here's my code:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3
import os, sys, time
import subprocess
from datetime import datetime, timedelta, date
from threading import Timer

server = subprocess.Popen('./start.sh', stdin=subprocess.PIPE,shell=True)
#junk variables
content = ''
previousContent = ''

def restart():
    if datetime.today().weekday() is 3:
        server.stdin.write(bytes('stop\r\n', 'ascii'))
        server.stdin.flush()
        time.sleep(90)
        print('Restarting...')
        os.system('python3 start.py')
        sys.exit()
    else:
        timerStart()

def timerStart():
    today = datetime.today()
    restartDate = today.replace(day=today.day,hour=1,minute=0,second=0,microsecond=0) + timedelta(days=1)
    delta_t = restartDate-today
    secs= delta_t.total_seconds()
    t=Timer(secs, restart)
    t.start()

timerStart()

while True:
    time.sleep(0.1)
    
    #stdout
    f = open('logs/latest.log')
    content = f.read()
    if previousContent != '':
        if previousContent in content:
            content.replace(previousContent,'')
            if content != '':
                print(content)
    previousContent = f.read()
    f.close()

    #stdin
    command = input('')
    if command:
        if command == 'stop':
            server.stdin.write(bytes('stop\r\n', 'ascii'))
            server.stdin.flush()
            time.sleep(20)
            sys.exit()
        else:
            server.stdin.write(bytes(command + '\r\n', 'ascii'))
            server.stdin.flush()
```

If someone could at least put me on the right track, it would really help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When instantiate the threading.Timer class, and call its start() method in the corresponding object, a new non-daemon execution thread is created and started behind the scenes for execute the method "restart". The created execution thread, waits for the time interval specified in the "secs" variable when instantiated the threading.Timer class to elapse, and then executes the specified "restart" method. The reason why the execution of the script does not end when you invoke sys.exit(), is because the main execution thread of the application, in order to finish its execution (and thus the execution of the script), has to wait for all other non-daemon threads created to finish first. That is, when you call sys.exit(), the process's main execution thread, will have to wait for the thread created by the instantiation of the threading.Timer class, to finish its execution. To solve that, what you can do, as you mentioned, is to call t.cancel(). Now for that, you must first move the declaration of the variable "t" to the global scope, to be able to use it in the 'timerStart' function, and in the block of code executed to handle the "stop" command. For example, after the declaration and initialization of the variable "previousContent", you can declare there the variable t and initialize it to None. Then, before assign to it the instance of threading.Timer, you have to use the "global" keyword that allows to modify the variable outside the current scope(outside the scope of the 'timerStart' function), and finally, when processing the "stop" command, call t.cancel(). In short, the final code would look like this:

```
# ! /usr/bin/env python3
import os, sys, time
import subprocess
from datetime import datetime, timedelta, date
from threading import Timer

server = subprocess.Popen('./start.sh', stdin=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
# junk variables
content = ''
previousContent = ''
t = None


def restart():
    if datetime.today().weekday() is 3:
        server.stdin.write(bytes('stop\r\n', 'ascii'))
        server.stdin.flush()
        time.sleep(90)
        print('Restarting...')
        os.system('python3 start.py')
        sys.exit()
    else:
        timerStart()


def timerStart():
    today = datetime.today()
    restartDate = today.replace(day=today.day, hour=1, minute=0, second=0, microsecond=0) + timedelta(days=1)
    delta_t = restartDate - today
    secs = delta_t.total_seconds()
    global t
    t = Timer(secs, restart)
    t.start()


timerStart()

while True:
    time.sleep(0.1)

    # stdout
    with open('logs/latest.log') as f:
        # Is better to open the file using a "with", such that the file is guaranteed to be closed,
        # even in the case of an exception
        content = f.read()
        if previousContent != '':
            if previousContent in content:
                content.replace(previousContent, '')
                if content != '':
                    print(content)
        previousContent = f.read()

    # stdin
    command = input('')
    if command:
        if command == 'stop':
            # Abort the threading.Timer's non-daemon execution thread:
            t.cancel()
            # Blocks the calling thread until the thread whose join() method is called is terminated:
            t.join()
            server.stdin.write(bytes('stop\r\n', 'ascii'))
            server.stdin.flush()
            time.sleep(20)
            sys.exit()
        else:
            server.stdin.write(bytes(command + '\r\n', 'ascii'))
            server.stdin.flush()
```

Also, is good to know, that the thread created by instantiating the threading.Timer class, could be canceled, only before it start to execute the "restart" method. The class threading.Timer, inherits from threading.Thread, that is way it creates and fires the execution of a new non-daemon execution thread, when start() is called.

References:

[Timer Objects](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#timer-objects)
[Thread Objects](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#thread-objects)

Comment: Thanks, I'm not sure to fully understand the t.join() though, does it just prevent the Timer from restarting ? Also, even though the stop part works really well, I still get the broken pipe error after a restart, I'm gonna do researches on my side for that.

Comment: My pleasure. The call to t.join(), is to prevent the caller thread(the main thread), from execute the next instruction, until the Timer's thread has terminated. When t.cancel() is called, according to the Timer class source code, it sets an Event that was instantiated in the constructor of the class, and in which is waiting the Timer's thread using the time interval. The call t.cancel() doesn't wait for the termination of the Timer's thread, so the join guarantees to wait for the Timer's thread termination, before proceed execution. After call t.cancel(), the timer will never restart again

Comment: I think you should refactor your code, since in my opinion, it's not a very good approach, that in order to restart the minecraft process, to have to be restarting your script once and again with the calls to os.system and sys.exit. I hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

If the only thing you are doing with the threads is restarting the script, you could try something simpler.  If you setup a signal handler for a timer interrupt, then launch a timer that will fire when you want the code to restart, you can skip all the threading stuff.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import signal
...other imports...

def do_restart(signal_num, frame):
    server.stdin.write(bytes('stop\r\n', 'ascii'))
    server.stdin.flush()
    time.sleep(90)
    print('Restarting...')
    os.system('python3 start.py')
        sys.exit()

...calculate how long before the restart...

signal.signal(signal.SIGALRM, do_restart)
signal.alarm(seconds_until_restart)

while True:
    time.sleep(0.1)
    
    #stdout
    f = open('logs/latest.log')
    content = f.read()
    if previousContent != '':
        if previousContent in content:
            content.replace(previousContent,'')
            if content != '':
                print(content)
    previousContent = f.read()
    f.close()

    #stdin
    command = input('')
    if command:
        if command == 'stop':
            server.stdin.write(bytes('stop\r\n', 'ascii'))
            server.stdin.flush()
            time.sleep(20)
            sys.exit()
        else:
            server.stdin.write(bytes(command + '\r\n', 'ascii'))
            server.stdin.flush()
```